# Convert Postgres Aggregate Function to Inline Array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, standard-deviation

I've been asked how to do a standard deviation on a variable list of values within a row.  For example:

```
select
  name, x, y, z, stddev (x, y, z)
from foo;
```

or

```
select
  order_no, a, b, c, d, e, f, stddev (a, b, c, d, e, f)
from foo;
```

So essentially just like `min` => `least` and `max` => `greatest`, I'd like a similar way to turn the aggregate stddev into a "normal" function.

I have been able to create a custom function to calculate standard deviation based on the standard formula, but I can't help but prefer to use the built-in function, if possible.  I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION std_deviation(variadic inputs numeric[])
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  result numeric;
BEGIN

  select stddev (unnest (inputs))
  into result;

  return result;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And it complains:

```
ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

There is no shortage of traffic on this error message, but I can't quite figure out how to apply the fix to my simple function.

Or, is there a better way to do this from the beginning?

Comment: Which line generates the error message?

Comment: Here is a simplified example that creates the error: `select min (unnest (array[1, 2, 3]))`.  I'm open to any method that achieves my end result, however, (of getting the standard deviation to work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set-returning functions (SRF) -- such as `unnest` -- in the `SELECT` clause is a PostgreSQL specific extension of the SQL standard. And usually doesn't worth to use it (because it's not what it looks like). Also, *SRFs cannot be used within aggregate functions*.

Use these SRF functions in the `FROM` clause instead (and use sub-selects where needed):

```
SELECT name, x, y, z, (SELECT stddev(v) FROM unnest(ARRAY[x, y, z]) v)
FROM foo
```

If you really want to write a function for that, use the `SQL` language (it's more clear & PostgreSQL can optimize their use):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION std_deviation(variadic inputs numeric[])
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
  SELECT stddev(v) FROM unnest(inputs) v
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.std_deviation(VARIADIC inputs numeric[])
RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
result numeric;
BEGIN

with foo as (
select unnest (inputs) as bar
)
select stddev (bar)
into result
from foo;

return result;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out pgnumerics already has a function for this.

```
-- test=# select pgnumerics.stdev('{1345,1301,1368,1322,1310,1370,1318,1350,1303,1299}');
--       stdev
-- ------------------
--  27.4639157198435
-- (1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pgnumerics.stdev (
  X double precision []
) RETURNS double precision
AS $$
DECLARE
  s double precision;
  N integer;
  i integer;
  xx double precision;
  sx double precision;
BEGIN
  N := array_upper(X,1) - array_lower(X,1) + 1;
  xx:= 0.0;
  sx:= 0.0;
  for i in 1..N loop
    xx:= xx + X[i]*X[i];
    sx:= sx + X[i];
  end loop;
  s := sqrt((N*xx - sx*sx) / (N*(N-1.0)));
  return s;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

http://pgnumerics.projects.pgfoundry.org/